# C# - Get Date from Int Value

Tags: c#, datetime, jwt

Good day,

I'm trying to check if an token expiration date is already expired. I'm using JWT in generating my token. I'm able to check in my javascript environment if my token is still valid by using this code.

```
if (decodedToken.exp < new Date().getTime() / 1000) {
    alert("Session expired);
}

// decodedToken.exp returns a value like "1556797243"
```

But my problem is, I don't know how to validate using C# code if the token is already expired.

I tried something like this,

```
// suppose I have a value of "1556797243"
var expirationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expiration, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET has a built-in way to parse a Unix timestamp, but it's on DateTimeOffset, not DateTime, as you might expect:

```
var expirationTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(expiration).UtcDateTime;
```

If expiration is a string you'd need to parse it into a long first:

```
var expirationTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(expiration)).UtcDateTime;
```

Comment: But there would be no problem right? whether I get the datetimeoffset rather than datetime?

Comment: The last `.DateTime` part converts a `DateTimeOffset` to a `DateTime`

Comment: Though not completely wrong to use `.DateTime`, you'd be better off using `.UtcDateTime`, which properly sets the `.Kind` of the result to `DateTimeKind.Utc` instead of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

Comment: Good point, edited to use `UtcDateTime`!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to convert from `unixTime` to `DateTime`

```
public static class DateUtil
    {
    private static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
    {
        return Epoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTime).ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

```
var expirationDate  = DateUtil.FromUnixTime(yourtime);
```

Comment: I can't find the `DateUtil`

Comment: I understand, but my `exp` is a string. not a long. So I'm having an error

Comment: you can use var expirationDate  = DateUtil.FromUnixTime(long.Parse(expiration));

Answer (score 0):

For UTC + 3 you can calculate with this extension methods:

```
public static long GetTokenExpirationTime(this string token)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtHandler = new();
    JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
    string tokenExp = jwtToken.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type.Equals("exp")).Value;
    return long.Parse(tokenExp);
}

public static TokenExpireModel CheckTokenIsValid(this string token)
{
    long tokenTicks = token.GetTokenExpirationTime();
    DateTime tokenDate = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(tokenTicks).UtcDateTime.AddHours(3);
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3);

    return new TokenExpireModel(tokenDate, now, tokenDate >= now);
}

public record TokenExpireModel(DateTime TokenDate, DateTime TodayDate, bool IsValid);
```